# Solving a kinematics problem involving areas under curve

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area, kinematics

The Original question is as follows:

> Two cars $A$ and $B$ simultaneously start a race. Velocity $v$ of the car $A$ varies with time $t$ according to graph shown. It acquires a velocity of $50 m/s$ few seconds before $t=100s$ and thereafter moves with this speed. Car $B$ runs together with car $A$  till both acquire a velocity of $20m/s$, after this car $B$ moves with zero acceleration for **one** second and then follows $v-t$ profile identical to car $A$ with a delay of $1$ second. In this way, car $B$ acquires a velocity of $50m/s$ one second after car$ A$ acquires it. How much more distance($\Delta s$) does car $A$ cover in first $100s$ as compared to car $B$ ?

[image: Car A velocity time profile]

**My efforts:**

Let both the cars move for $t_0$ seconds till they both acquire velocity of $20 m/s$. With the help of question, I draw the curve for car $B$ alongside the car $A$ (shown below). Hence, the answer to the question is the shaded area as shown below.

[image: Velocity time profile of both A and B shown alongside]

Let $S_A$ be the area (distance) travelled by car $A$ between the time interval $[t_0, 100]$ and $S_B$ be the area (distance) travelled by car $B$ between the time interval $[t_0, 100]$ . Then required area is $S_A - S_B$.

Now,

$$S_A = \int_{t_0}^{100}v_A(t)dt$$

and

$$S_B= 20 + \int_{t_0+1}^{100}v_B(t)dt$$

The $20$ in $S_B$ accounts for the rectangular area where car $B$ travels with zero acceleration.

Also, according to question, $v_B(t) = v_A(t-1)$ because car $B$ is delayed by $1$ second.

Hence, the answer($\Delta s$)should be :

$$\Delta s= \int_{t_0}^{100}v_A(t)dt - \int_{t_0+1}^{100}v_A(t-1)dt-20$$

I didn't included the distance travelled between $t=0$ to $t=t_0$ because they are same for both cars and will cancel out.

I'm stucked here as the integrals don't seem to be solved because nothing is known about the exact expression for $v_A(t)$. How can I proceed further and if there's something wrong I did ?

(P.S.: According to answer key, $\Delta s=30m$)

Comment: You're not visualizing it correctly. Car $A$ reaches $50$ $\text{m/s}$ a few seconds before $100$ seconds. Then in that short time interval leading up to $100$ seconds, Car $A$ maintains a constant velocity of $50$ $\text{m/s}$. The same goes for Car $B$ except it is late by $1$ second, but it still maintains a constant velocity of $50$ $\text{m/s}$ barely before $100$ seconds.  So ideally, you can actually integrate from the moment Car $B$ starts maintaining a constant rate of $20$ $\text{m/s}$ up to the moment when Car $B$ reaches $50$ $\text{m/s}$. Can you continue from there?

Comment: @Accelerator "but it still maintains a constant velocity of 50
 m/s
 *barely before $100$
 seconds"* How can we be sure that it'll get to $50m/s$ before $t=100$. Suppose $A$ makes to $50 m/s$ at $t = 99.9$, then $B$ will get to $50 m/s$ at $t = 100.9$ which is greater than $100.$

Comment: We are supposing Car $A$ reaches $50$ $\text{m/s}$ a few seconds before the 100-second mark hits. Maybe it's 2 seconds, 3 seconds, 5 seconds, or something. 0.1 seconds is not a few seconds. At the very least, a few seconds could be considered 2 seconds. In that case, Car $A$ would reach $50$ $\text{m/s}$ at $t = 98$ and Car $B$ would reach $50$ $\text{m/s}$ at $t=99$.

Comment: We would consider the possibility that Car $A$ could reach $50$ $\text{m/s}$ if the problem said that it reaches that velocity at *any* moment before the 100-second mark (like $t=99.9$, $t=99.99$, $t=94$, etc.). If the question was phrased like that, then yes, Car $B$ could reach $50$ $\text{m/s}$ after the 100-second mark depending on when Car $A$ reaches that same velocity, and my argument would get thrown out the window.

Comment: @Accelerator okay thanks. I thought that it could be other than integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note this key bit of information: "It acquires a velocity of $50$ m/s few seconds before $t=100$ s".

Let's rearrange B's speed profile. Take that second where B drives a constant $20$ m/s, and move it to the end:

[image]

This doesn't change the area under the curve for B. It just rearranges it. Thus the distance travelled is still the same. But now the speed profile for B is identical to that of A for the first 99 seconds. For that hundredth second, A has already reached its max speed of $50$ m/s, while B has suddenly dropped to $20$ m/s, so there is a $1$ second period with a $30$ m/s difference in their speed. Thus the distance travelled is $30$ m less for B.

You can also discover this from your integral equation:
$$\Delta s= \int_{t_0}^{100}v_A(t)dt - \int_{t_0+1}^{100}v_A(t-1)dt-20$$
In the second integral, we make the substitution $t' = t-1$ and we get $\int_{t_0}^{99}v_A(t')dt'$ and so
$$\begin{align}\Delta s &= \int_{t_0}^{100}v_A(t)dt - \int_{t_0}^{99}v_A(t')dt'-20 \\&= \int_{99}^{100}v_A(t)dt-20\\&=\int_{99}^{100}50dt-20\\&=30\end{align}$$

Comment: According to your last second line integral,  $v_A=50$ for $t\in [99,100]$ . But how can we be sure of that ? Of course the velocity reaches $50$ before $t=100$ , but how we can be sure that $t=99$ is included in there ? What if it reaches $50 m/s$ at $t = 99.9$ , then we cannot substitute $50$ there ?

Comment: The rearrangement of graph is a nice method. Thanks !

Comment: *"For that hundredth second, A has already reached its max speed of 50"* . How can we be sure ? What if $A$ reached max of $50m/s$ at say $t=99.5$  ? How are we sure that it must reach $50$ at $99$ or before, why not somewhere between $99$ and $100$ ?

Comment: The very first line of my post was devoted to quoting the line in your question that said so, calling it a key bit of information. A reaches its max speed of $50$ m/s **a few seconds** before the $100$ second mark. "Few" implies more than $1$.

Comment: Actually, the rearrangement of the graph and the substitution in the integration are doing the exact same thing. They both shift the graph of B after $t_0 + 1$ one second left. Then the $1$ second interval with B at $20$ m/s is added in.

Comment: Okay thanks. I thought few could also mean fractional.